# Is there any alternate way to replace complex enum?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I have a complex enum class in my spring boot application which holds different status values for different systems.

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public enum Status {
    FOO_STATUS("Status1" ,"status_1", "STATUS_1", "stat1"),
    BAR_STATUS("Status2" ,"status_2", "STATUS_2", "stat2" ),
    FOO1_STATUS("Status3" ,"status_3", "STATUS_3", "stat3" ),
    BAR1_STATUS("Status4" ,"status_4", "STATUS_4", "stat4" ),
    ....
    ....
    ....

    private final String system1Status;
    private final String system2Status;
    private final String system3Status;
    private final String system4Status;
    private static Map<String, String> statusMap;

    Status(String system1Status, String system2Status, String system3Status, String system4Status) {
        this.system1Status = system1Status;
        this.system2Status = system2Status;
        this.system3Status = system3Status;
        this.system4Status = system4Status;
    }


    public String getSystem1Status() {
        return system1Status;
    }

    public String getSystem2Status() {
        return system2Status;
    }

    public String getSystem3Status() { 
        return system3Status;
    }

    public String getSystem4Status() {
        return system4Status;
    }

    private static void initializeMapping() {
        statusMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Status map : Status.values()) {
            statusMap.put(map.getSystem1Status(), map.getSystem2Status());
        }
    }

    public static String getSystem2StatusForSytem1Status(String status) {
        if (statusMap == null) {
            initializeMapping();
        }
        if (statusMap.containsKey(status)) {
            return statusMap.get(status);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getSystem3StatusForSytem1Status(String status) {
        ....
    }

    public static String getSystem4StatusForSytem2Status(String status) {
        ....
    }

    public static String getSystem3StatusForSytem2Status(String status) {
        ....
    }
    
    ....
    
    ....

}
```

The enum holds status string mapping for various systems. It also has methods to get different system status by supplying the current system status.

Ex: We can get System1 status by sending the System 2 status value.

As the enum is getting more complex , is there any alternate way to hold this static data?

PS: I know this can be moved to a reference table in DB, But I am looking for any alternate within the code (like loading from yaml file).

Comment: "*I am looking for any alternate within the code (like loading from yaml file)*" My suggestion is load from yaml file. Sorry but this question too broad. Stack Overflow is for *specific* programming questions ("why does this code throw this exception?" etc.). This basically boils down to "recommend me an architecture". There are many, equally viable solutions, and different people will have different opinions about what's best.

Comment: Sure, you can add that mapping through code or configuration files. I'd suggest providing a mapping of enum + system to system-specific status and maybe vice versa. Since this may be some complex code maybe try to move that to a separate class for separation of concerns: enum to represent the status and the other class to do the mapping/config loading.

Comment: Exactly which aspect of the complexity of the enum do you hope to simplify?

Comment: [1/2]
The concern about the `enum` getting more and more complex is only valid if that complexity is accidental, not inherent.
Otherwise, switching to a different approach would just move that complexity elsewhere (which kind of seems to be the case in your example).

I think it makes sense keep the `enum` (even if it grows complex) iif the following conditions are met:
- There is no reasonable scenario in which you would want/need to account for new statuses or new mappings (or drop existing ones) without changing the code.

Comment: [2/2]
- You rely on at least some `enum` features available out of the box, so you would have to reimplement those by hand. E.g. `values()` listed in a determinate order, `valueOf()` used with canonical String labels, `ordinal()` to infer position, `compareTo()`, `name()`, serialization, etc..
- You use the enum constants polymorphically (and maybe you need to alter the behavior for some of them without a full-fledged class hierarchy) or you want to leverage the compiler check for exhaustive case branches in switch expressions (with newer java versions).

Comment: @Michael How is this question broader? I am asking for an alternate solution for the given use case. I have came across many such question within the community. This is very specific question which is to get the alternate/replace a complex enum in java.

Comment: @DarkCrow "*I have came across many such question*" Yep, you're right; there are many off-topic questions asked here. "*This is very specific question*" Nope. It isn't. This is a system design question, and there's an infinite number of possible solutions /answers. How to implement this is purely a matter of personal opinion. Opinion-based questions are specifically off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The concern about the enum getting more and more complex is only valid if that complexity is accidental, not inherent. Otherwise, switching to a different approach would just move that complexity elsewhere (which kind of seems to be the case in your example). I think it makes sense to keep the enum (even if it grows complex) iif the following conditions are met:

- There is no reasonable scenario in which you would want/need to account for new statuses or new mappings (or drop existing ones) without changing the code.
- You rely on at least some enum features available out of the box, so you would have to reimplement those by hand. E.g. values() listed in a determinate order, valueOf() used with canonical String labels, ordinal() to infer position, compareTo(), name(), serialization, etc.
- You use the enum constants polymorphically (and maybe you need to alter the behavior for some of them without a full-fledged class hierarchy) or you want to leverage the compiler check for exhaustive case branches in switch expressions (with newer java versions).

Comment: I just pasted my old comment(s) as an answer now, to make them more readable (and because the writeup was originally concieved as an answer, but the question got closed while I was still typing). :)